# Saving utf-8 xml to file won't show as shown in browser

Tags: python, xml, unicode

In python3 I download an xml file from the web
https://cds.cern.ch/record/1642553?&of=xm&ot=245
I then try to save it.

If I open the URL on the browser I get (between the lines):
W± boson in pp collisions at √s = 7 TeV

If I open the file on my pc it shows:
WÂ± boson in pp collisions at âs = 7 TeV

the b'string outputs:
W\xc3\x82\xc2\xb1 boson in pp collisions at \xc3\xa2\xc2\x88\xc2\x9as = 7 TeV

```py
import requests
import codecs

cdsUrl = 'https://cds.cern.ch/record/1642553?&of=xm&ot=245'
cdsXml = requests.get(cdsUrl)

f = codecs.open("output.txt", "w", "utf-8-sig")
f.write(cdsXml.text)
f.close()
```

I am trying to be able to read the file and correctly show the content as the browser does.

Comment: in what program do you open it ? does this program have font with this char? Is this program using UTF-8 to display text ?

Comment: I open the output file in either Sublime Text 3 and Vim.

Comment: when I add `print(cdsXml.encoding)` then it shows `ISO-8859-1`. It seems server sends it as  `ISO-8859-1`, not `utf-8`

Comment: Super @furas. I guess I missed something... So I misunderstand the meaning of the header "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"

Comment: this header is part of XML, not part of HTTP procol.  HTTP protocol uses own headers to inform browser what type of data is send from server and what encoding and compressing it will use.

Comment: thank you very much. your help was very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems server sends information that it will send data encoded `ISO-8859-1`

```
 print(cdsXml.encoding)
```

but it sends data encoded `utf-8` - but `requests` uses `ISO-8859-1` to encode it.

But if you encode it manually using `utf-8` then you get correct chars.

```
 print( cdsXml.content.decode('utf-8') )
```

Code:

```
import requests
import codecs

cdsUrl = 'https://cds.cern.ch/record/1642553?&of=xm&ot=245'
cdsXml = requests.get(cdsUrl)

print(cdsXml.encoding)

text = cdsXml.content.decode('utf-8')

f = codecs.open("output.txt", "w", "utf-8-sig")
f.write(text)

f.close()
```